# Find the biggest number using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find the biggest number in a webpage (it is not my webpage).
Do I need javascript?

First I need to get the values from all the **SPAN.f** elements. Then, I must to compare the numbers into them to find out the biggest value.
How?

Let's say I've got `220 - 340 - 480 × 360 - 25/7/2012` from all the **SPAN.f** elements.

I need `480` to be highlighted, but I don't want `/2012` to be highlighted because is part of the date. I mean, I want to highlight the `480`, not the `/2012`.

I use GreaseMonkey with Firefox Nightly 22

THIS IS THE SCRIPT, but it does not work for me:

```
 // ==UserScript==
 // @name MAX NUMBER in page
 // @include https://www.google.com/search*
 // @version 1
 // @grant none
 // ==/UserScript==

 var spans = document.querySelectorAll("SPAN.f");
 var max = -Infinity;
 var maxSpan;
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(span) {
 var val = Number(span.textContent);
 if (max < val)
 {
 max = val;
 maxSpan = span;
 }
 });
 if (maxSpan) maxSpan.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

Try the code in the page into this link:
https://www.google.com/search?hl=es&tbs=sbi%3AAMhZZitcQmshs1XQVAv0-EH8Ix_18bqev3_1smHm0uRMYGzjaSYpDr6KHQ_1tWEwNyvZGPus4-VWnfO9P9071ZllBMIC3amGAveNcz_1uYWteP9OKZ1Si1Yz0urBuyIWQbBTQIue4Gntn5J8FIxaLI1kEHMdI2BIh6mrM6YGiMBT6DJyLlW4K-1kE0n_1d2fnXoNxKDd4jM034f9ctLfUYb4WvSaptVZknw_1jhHBFu9HeINrN15ha7k9Kzz1Ifm_1P5y7Vxws_1Qjr48P-rXcoqneksiRnfQyXwTGJeuMAD0wtgNnXubqYgzrPkxbZ-BonJ9Hgxvy5pv6lfEsGIuNzrtxd6QFdDKAP5keREmQ&ei=vTkuU87gBKay2wWU0IHoBg&ved=0CAgQiBw&biw=1024&bih=624&dpr=1

Comment: Match numbers with a regular expression and then find the largest with the `Math.max()` method.

Comment: This is not appropriate for regex, although regex could certainly be used to find the numbers. Then use JavaScript to find the biggest one.

Answer (score 1):

`24/Dec/1789` is not a valid number, but should be a string, the others are numbers, and you can do

```
var biggest = Math.max(100, 220, 340);
```

If what you've got is a string, you could do

```
var str = '100 - 220 - 340 - 24/Dec/1789';

var biggest = Math.max.apply(null, str.split('-').filter(function(x) {
    return !isNaN(x);
}));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cZGR/2/);

Comment: First I need to get the values from a SPAN.f element.  How can I do that?

Comment: @Sam-Bo - I have no idea, post the HTML in the question and point out exactly what it is you're trying to get ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you mean finding the largest number contained in `SPAN` elements having the class `f` (this is what the syntax `SPAN.f` stands for).
If so you don't need a regular expression and you don't even need to sort the values. Just iterate once over each value to find the smallest one.
Something like this:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("SPAN.f");
var max = -Infinity;
var maxSpan;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(span) {
    var val = Number(span.textContent);
    if (max < val)
    {
        max = val;
        maxSpan = span;
    }
});
if (maxSpan) maxSpan.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/C35W6/